# Deploy hook syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, deployment

Trying to give permissions to /public/uploads with deploy hook,  during cloud66 deploy to digitalocean, to get carrierwave file uploads working.
I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error during deployment: Error during after_rails hook: Execution of sudo 
/tmp/open_folder_permissions.sh returned a non-zero exit code. Output was: 
/tmp/open_folder_permissions.sh:5: syntax error, unexpected tGVAR, expecting keyword_do or 
'{' or '(' sudo chmod 0775 -R $RAILS_STACK_PATH/public/uploads ^
```

open_folder_permissions.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
#load environment variables
source /var/.cloud66_env
#assign desired permissions
sudo chmod 0775 -R $RAILS_STACK_PATH/public/uploads
```

deploy_hooks.yml

```
production:
  after_rails:
    - source: /.cloud66/files/open_folder_permissions.sh
      destination: /tmp/open_folder_permissions.sh
      target: rails                
      execute: true
      run_on: all_servers
      apply_during: all
      sudo: true
```

What could cause the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `open_folder_permissions.sh` doesn't contain valid Ruby code. From the looks of it, it's supposed to be a shell script, not a Ruby script, so you should change the shebang line to a shell interpreter instead of a Ruby interpreter.

`#! bin/bash` is the right interpreter.

Comment: I think `#! /bin/sh˛did it`, but now i got another error:
    `Error during deployment: Error during after_rails hook: Execution of sudo /tmp/open_folder_permissions.sh returned a non-zero exit code. Output was: /tmp/open_folder_permissions.sh: 3: /tmp/open_folder_permissions.sh: source: not found chmod: cannot access /public/uploads': No such file or directory` Basically it doesn't find the directories. Could it be it doesn't search in Rails_path/public/uploads, just /public/uploads?

Comment: `#! /bin/bash` was the solution